# Is it possible to see the event log when using eth_call?

Tags: web3js, truffle, json-rpc

I want to perform a transaction locally (with the `call` method in web3 which perform a `eth_call` RPC call). It returns only the return value of the function called and I want to see the event log.

I considered sending a transaction with a 0 gas price, then reading logs from the transaction receipt. According to [parity documentation](https://wiki.parity.io/JSONRPC-eth-module#eth_gettransactionreceipt) :

> **Note** That the receipt is available even for pending transactions.

In my case the receipt is null until the transaction is mined, so that solution does not work.

To sum up my question, how to read the event log when executing a transaction locally ?

Comment: AFAIK there's no standard way to achieve that. One posibility is to modify an implementation of the EVM an execute the call there.

Comment: did you manage to work it out? I have the same issue